Cant Install SQL Server 2022 on Ubuntu 2022.04, no message or errors found
Im trying to install SQL SERVER 2022 on Ubuntu 22.04, I follow the steps on official microsoft SQL Ubuntu Install, and all good using a VPS on Hostinger, but following the same steps with VPS on Contabo the instalation is stuck.
First with this all is ok, and show the SQL KEY:
curl -fsSL https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc
Next with this, the prosess is stuck, never continues. Cant generate the pgp file, without this cant download the installer.
sudo gpg --dearmor -o /usr/share/keyrings/microsoft-prod.gpg
I try the other method and same, is stuck using this commands:
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc
sudo tee /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/microsoft.asc
First i was installing some ubuntu components, with others try, i reinstall Ubuntu and try all steps and same issues.
This my screen:
Fail Step
